# does composition of maps is smooth and one map is smooth imply the other is also smooth?

Tags: differential-topology

If $f\circ g$ is smooth and $f$ is smooth, does it follow that $g$ is smooth? Note that I cannot simply take the inverse of $f$. Do I have to use implicit function theorem?

Comment: If $f$ is constant, $g$ can be as wild as it wishes. If $f$ is a local diffeomorphism (or immersion), then $g$ must be smooth too.

Comment: Duh, thank you. Got too involved into messy details and lost track of simple facts...

Comment: @DanielFischer That looks like an answer to me ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A composition of functions can smooth out irregular behaviour of either partner. If $f$ is constant, you cannot say anything about $g$. If $f$ is locally invertible, however (e.g. a local diffeomorphism), and $g$ is continuous, then the smoothness of the composition implies the smoothness of $g$.